# Trying to understand linking procedure for writing Python/C++ hybrid

Tags: c++, python

I want to start learning more about using SWIG and other methods to interface Python and C++. To get started, I wanted to compile this simple program mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824949/how-to-solve-the-segmentation-fault-when-hybrid-programming-of-c-python):

```
#include <Python.h> 

 int main() 
 { 
      Py_Initialize(); 
      PyRun_SimpleString ("import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ely/Desktop/Python/C-Python/')");

      PyObject* pModule = NULL; 
      PyObject* pFunc   = NULL; 

      pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("hello");
      if(pModule == NULL){
           printf("Error importing module.");
           exit(-1);
      }


      pFunc   = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "Hello"); 
      PyEval_CallObject(pFunc, NULL); 
      Py_Finalize(); 
      return 0; 
 }
```

where the file "hello.py" just has the contents:

```
 def Hello():
     print "Hello world!"
```

**Note:** I already have python2.7-dev and python-dev and libboost-python-dev installed. But when I go to compile the code, I get errors that I believe are due to incorrectly linking to the Python libraries.

```
 ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 test.cpp    /tmp/ccVnzwDp.o: In function `main':
 test.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
 test.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `PyImport_ImportModule'
 test.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
 test.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords'
 test.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
 /tmp/ccVnzwDp.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was fishing around for examples of this online, and I found the following syntax, which causes the code to compile into an object file, but then I am unable to actually execute the file.

```
 ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ gcc -c -g -I/usr/include/python2.7 test.cpp 
 ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ ./test.o
 bash: ./test.o: Permission denied
 ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ chmod ug=rx ./test.o
 ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ ./test.o
 bash: ./test.o: cannot execute binary file
 ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ sudo chmod ug=rx ./test.o
 ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ ./test.o
 bash: ./test.o: cannot execute binary file
```

The same behavior as above is still seen if I use `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Help in understanding my error in linking would be great, and even better for any sort of explanation that helps me understand the "logic" behind the kind of linking I need to do, so that I'll remember better what possible things I am forgetting the next time. Thanks!

Comment: Another remark: you cannot execute `.o` files directly. First you need to link them into an `ELF` executable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are seeing are linker errors. To fix those, you need to link `python2.7` library.

Try next line :

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 test.c -lpython2.7
```

it should work.

Comment: What is `kel.cpp`? Should that be replaced with my example file `test.cpp`? If so, then I still get an error: 


     `ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Python/C-Python$ gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 test.cpp -lpython2.7` gives the error:
     `/tmp/ccaahL1m.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @EMS I named the file kel.cpp. Fixed in the edit. That is weird that you get an error. Which distro are you using?

Comment: @EMS, compile with `g++` not `gcc`.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 11.04, gcc version is: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.5-15ubuntu1) 4.4.5

Comment: It compiles and links fine using gcc 4.6.1 on fedora 15.

Comment: Yes, with g++ it worked. I also had to make a slight correction to the c++ code, because I had to give it the path to the Python module. Now it works.

Comment: If I may ask: how should you do when compiling a constructor file ? That is, test.c is the constructor for a header file but with Python calls in it ? Because -lpython2.7 needs a reference to main apparently. I am allowing myself to ask this here as the answer is strongly related to a question on which my project is blocked. (I have also asked a question here btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182421/linking-c-object-files-embedded-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

First, do you compile C or C++ code?

Use `gcc` for the former, and `g++` for the latter. C++ code needs some additional linking to be performed.

Second: you have to link your program to `libpython2.7.so` to embed the interpreter into it. To do this, add `-lpython2.7` to gcc command line.

Answer (score 1):

`test.o` is not your executable file, that's why you can't execute it.

The default name for your program is `a.out`, try running that. You can specify a name for your program using the `-o` option.