# Compile python code and link it to C++ program?

Tags: python, c++

I am well aware of the many possibilities that exist to allow C code to run python code, and vice versa (Cython, Boost.Python, ...). However, unless I am mistaken, all those approaches merely "call" the relevant python scripts and manage the interactions between the C program and the python script. Therefore, an installation of python is required.

In my situation, I would like a stand-alone solution, where my python code can be somehow compiled and linked to my main C++ program. I had hopes with Cython, as it allowed me to compile my script and create a .so file. However, I don't seem to have been able to "link" that .so file to my C++ program. I attempted the following:

A simple python script containing a function multiply(a,b) which returns a*b ; I created a libmultiply.so file using cython.
A short Cpp file which outputs the result of multiply(5,2):

```
int multiply(int, int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << multiply(5,2) << std::endl;
}
```

I build by doing : **g++ test.cpp -L/home/jerome/ -lmultiply**

Which gives me the error :

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `multiply(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure if what I tried makes sense, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Cython can't do that.  It outputs code which links to the Python/C API.  Unless that API is available, anything you build out of Cython isn't going to work.  It also (AFAIK) does some fairly aggressive name mangling.

Comment: You can't 'compile' Python code; it works off a VM. However, you can 'freeze' it, with something like '[PyInstaller](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller)' (which can create DLLs/SOs). Is that what you're trying to do? Or maybe "[trying  to understand linking procedure for writing python/c hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826311/trying-to-understand-linking-procedure-for-writing-python-c-hybrid?rq=1)" will help.

Comment: @snotwaffle You can compile it.  You just have to write the compiler:-) (since I'm not aware of one that is readily available).

Comment: You do realize that when you write `def multiply(a, b): return a * b` in Python, the corresponding function in C++ is _not_ `int multiply( int a, int b);`, but something more like `boost::any multiply( boost::any a, boost::any b );`.  Except, of course, that it knows nothing about `boost::any`; the actual function would have a signature like `PyObject* multiply( PyObject*, PyObject* ).  And once you've got all of the support for `PyObject`, you might as well link in `python.dll`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, you're right, of course, but that would be using a sledgehammer to hit a thumb-tack in the case of the question asked.

Comment: @snotwaffle Except that that's why he can't possibly find a signature for his Python function.

Answer (score 3):

[Shed Skin](https://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) is the closest thing I could find.  It compiles a typed subset of Python to c++.  Probably not as robust as you'd like but this is an odd use case. If you feel like writing up something yourself, you could look into [LLVM](http://llvm.org) which has been used to create things similar to what you want.

Edit 1:

I just found this list of awesome python things on github, [Awesome-python](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#admin-panels), and it links to [Pyston](https://github.com/dropbox/pyston) which is a python LLVM implementation.  May be a better fit for what you want or a starting point for a Python to C++ bridge.