# Linking C++ object files embedded with Python

Tags: c++, linker, header, shared-libraries, pybind11

I have a C++ constructor file (`formatting_SQ.cpp`) of a header file `formatting_SQ.h` which I want to link to other constructor files of header files (`neat.cpp nnode.cpp link.cpp etc...-> neat.h nnode.h link.h`) in order to have `formatting_SQ.o`.

Then, I want to link my main.cpp file with this `formatting_SQ.o` file. The problem is: `formatting_SQ` is embedded with python, and as far as my understanding goes, C++ embedded with Python needs the compiling flag `-lpython3.6m` on Linux: such flag requires a reference to a `main()` function, which I don't have in `formatting_SQ.cpp` because it's a constructor file meant to be an object file.

So I first tried to create object files for each constructor file and then link everything together *at once*:

```
g++ -c -O3 -Wall -fPIC -fopenmp -std=c++14 -lstdc++ `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` *.cpp 
g++ -o the_executable neat.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o network.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o population.o formatting_SQ.o main.o -fopenmp -O3 -Wall -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` -lpython3.6m
```

Here comes my first question: Are these command right or is there eventually a compilation flag missing ? This gives me a segmentation fault as I try to execute `./the_executable`.

Then, I tried to compile `formatting_SQ.cpp` independently with all other constructor files, but as expected, this doesn't work because there is no reference to main in `formatting_SQ.cpp`.

```
g++ -o temp_formatting neat.o nnode.o link.o trait.o gene.o network.o innovation.o organism.o species.o genome.o population.o formatting_SQ.o -fopenmp -O3 -Wall -fPIC `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` -lpython3.6m
```

So here comes my second question: how could I create a python embedded object file linking `formatting_SQ.cpp` with all other constructor files *without* having this `undefined reference to main` error ?

**formatting_SQ.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "formatting_SQ.h"
#include "neat.h"
#include "network.h"
#include "link.h"
#include "nnode.h"
#include "trait.h"
#include "gene.h"
#include "genome.h"
#include "innovation.h"
#include "organism.h"
#include "species.h"
#include "population.h"

namespace py = pybind11;
py::module compile_data = py::module::import("initialize");
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "formatting_SQ.h"
#include <omp.h>
    
namespace py = pybind11;
        
int main(int argc, char** argv){
      
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some long hours of research I can conclude that the compilation method is correct but BE EXTREMELY CAREFULL with where you declare your import modules from python, because this was the problem for me

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "formatting_SQ.h"
#include "neat.h"
#include "network.h"
#include "link.h"
#include "nnode.h"
#include "trait.h"
#include "gene.h"
#include "genome.h"
#include "innovation.h"
#include "organism.h"
#include "species.h"
#include "population.h"

namespace py = pybind11;
py::module compile_data = py::module::import("initialize"); DON'T DO THIS its wrong !!!
```

You must declare your modules locally otherwise there be some conflicts in the namespace as the same module may be imported more than once and this causes the segmentation fault.