# "Segmentation fault" when run python function in C++ code using Cmake

Tags: python, c++

I am learning to embed python code into c++ code. Following the simple example in [How to solve the 'Segmentation fault' when hybrid programming of C & Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824949/how-to-solve-the-segmentation-fault-when-hybrid-programming-of-c-python) and use `g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7 -L/usr/lib/python2.7 -lpython2.7` to compile the code and run the program, I can get the correct result.

But if I create a "build" folder and using CMake to run the program, it still has segmentation fault.

My CMakeList.txt is like below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project ( pyTest )


if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RELEASE")
endif()

string(ASCII 27 Esc)
set(Red "${Esc}[1;31m")
set(ColourReset "${Esc}[m")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "DEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -O0 -g")
MESSAGE(STATUS "${Red}BUILD TYPE: DEBUG${ColourReset}")
else()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -O3")
MESSAGE(STATUS "${Red}BUILD TYPE: RELEASE${ColourReset}")
endif()


include_directories( include )
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SRC_LIST2 main.cpp)

add_executable( pytest ${SRC_LIST2})
target_link_libraries(pytest ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

For convenience, I post my code below:

pytest.py

```
def Hello():
    print "Hello, world!"
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{

Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString ("import sys; sys.path.insert(0, 'DIRECTORY_PATH'");
PyObject * pModule = NULL;
PyObject * pFunc   = NULL;

pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("pytest");
pFunc   = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "Hello");
if(pFunc != NULL) {
    PyEval_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
    Py_Finalize();
}
else {
    printf("pFunc returned NULL\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

where "DIRECTORY_PATH" is the folder path of my main.cpp file and pytest.py, not the path of "build" folder

When I print out the result of PyImport_ImportModule, it returns 0. I think that means it doesn't get the python model. But my main.cpp and python file are under same directory, I don't know why it cannot get the model...

Can I fix it? Thx!

Comment: Can you post the error that you're getting?

Comment: @Displayname The error is just "Segmentation fault". No other messages...But when I print out the result of PyImport_ImportModule, it returns 0. I think that means it doesn't get the python model. But my main.cpp and python file is under same directory, I don't know why it cannot get the model...

Comment: The name of your module is `pytest`, not `test`. You should have checked the value returned by `PyImport_ImportModule` before using it.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I am sorry I just copied the code from the website I referred for convenience. In my code it IS 'pytest'. I just revised in my question.  But the problem still exists....

Comment: If you compile the program in the DEBUG mode and run under a debugger, you will know on what line does it segfault. That would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself. I should put main.cpp and pytest.py under same directory and use `PyRun_SimpleString ("import sys; sys.path.insert(0, 'DIRECTORY_PATH'");` to change 'DIRCTORY_PATH' to current directory that saves main.cpp and pytest.py. (Before I used a wrong dirctory so I got segmentation fault)